# Parenthesis in the URL nested routing - Angular v4

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am having a problem with the routing on my Angular app which adds a parenthesis to the URL when it should not.

I have a 'deep' nested routing, so I have been trying different approaches with not lucky.

I only have the problem at the very bottom of the nesting, so the last route possible

> where I expect this:
>
> http://localhost:4200/#/customers/1/overview
>
> I get this:
>
> http://localhost:4200/#/customers/1/(overview)

I decoupled the code from the project and created a simple sample on GitHub, so you can download it, and try with it (sorry, could not make it on plunkr)

https://github.com/ialex90/AngularErrorRouting

There are a couple of branches, trying different approaches,

Also, you can check this public link to see the behavior with more detailed.

https://angular-error-routing.netlify.com/#/dashboard

Any idea? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure. but looking in the source here : github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.0/packages/router/src/… @ line 428 found by search on '( it may be something that's meant to occur - and I'd hazard a guess it may have some sort of semantic meaning like optional parameters perhaps. Perhaps someone can confirm. AFAIK It doesn't break the functionality.

Comment: This is still "broken" in Angular 8. I am at a loss as to why this is the default behavior and cannot be overridden. If I want a "secondary" route, why I can add the damn parentheses myself? is that really so hard to figure? and Yes, I realize with about 40 lines of code, I can write my own URL serialize override. I just find it silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in no the nicer way, as my favorite solution would be with relative paths and I made it with absolute paths, but at least, it does work.

So, I changed the routerLink attribute within the HTML of the sidebar to be calling a method with the click output event, and the method is this:

```
sidebarLink(item: string) {
        let paths = window.location.hash.split('/');
        if (paths.length >= this.limitCharPositionURL) {
            paths = paths.slice(this.hashCharPosition, this.limitCharPositionURL);
            paths.push(item);
            paths[0] = '/' + paths[0];
            this._router.navigate(paths);
        }
    }
```

so I am building the path where limitCharPosition is 1 to remove the # from the location hash value returned. limitCharPositionURL would be 3 in this case, as the window.location.hash returns the following array:

['#', 'customers', 'id']

So to be sure that even if the url is longer, I cut it off at 3.

Then, I add the 'overview' or 'groups' or the link we need to the array. LAstly, I add the '/' to the first value to make the route navigation absolute.

You can find the solution in this repo:
https://github.com/ialex90/AngularErrorRouting/tree/Routing

And the demo working in this link:
https://neurologist-antelope-53654.netlify.com/#/dashboard

[image]

Hope it helps to someone else.

If you had same error and found another solution, please, share it :)

Answer (score 1):

add / at the beginning of the router link

```
[routerLink] = "/overview"
```

[Angular 5 child routes adding parentheses to the route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411505/angular-5-child-routes-adding-parentheses-to-the-route)